# How to customize windows frames(panels)

Tags: themes, gui, gtk, gtk3

I want to learn to customize GTK themes. So far I have managed to learn how to change the background(accent) color, text color etc..

I can change colors by changing the values in the files in /usr/share/themes//gtk-3.0/gtk.css.
By changing values in this code I can play with the colors.

```
/* default color scheme */

@define-color bg_color #cdc3b8;
@define-color fg_color #262626;
@define-color base_color #accdff;
@define-color text_color #262626;
@define-color selected_bg_color #01b9fc;
@define-color selected_fg_color #ffffff;
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #A3D0FF;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #023C79;
```

But where exactly in the theme are the files for the windows frames(panels) so I can change text of the tittlebar, change color of the frames ? If possible would really be helpful if you also say what code is for what purpose.

Tthank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Ubuntu with the Unity desktop environment and the Ambiance theme, the window titlebars get their CSS theming from the file `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css`, and the window buttons themselves can be found in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/unity/`. The "UnityDecoration" style properties are what you're looking for in the CSS.

For a full description of what all the different properties and files do, see the [Ubuntu Wiki's page on Unity theming](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming).